# Java Аккуратный ввод в консоль

Tags: java, консоль, ввод

Такая проблема - есть программа (пока-что в планах), которая будет асинхронно выводить информацию, и всегда будет доступен пользовательский ввод, что-то в духе:

```
[INFO] info...
[WARNING] warning...

$ (тут будет пользовательский ввод)
```

но, при очередном выводе, java просто перекроет своим выводом строку пользовательского ввода. как от этого можно избавиться? хотелось бы, чтобы строка для ввода всегда была отдельно от вывода, и еще такая программа должна открываться в командной строке, не создавая новых окон.

Comment: сам знаю, что возможно, ибо пользовался таким продуктом, на java.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону методов, устанавливающих позицию курсора в консоли. Идея в том, чтобы в момент вывода устанавливать позицию курсора на первую свободную строку, а потом устанавливать его обратно в самую нижнюю строку для ввода. Точнее не скажу, потому что знаю, как подобное оформить в шарпе, но не в джаве.

Answer (score 0):

В своем тестовом консольном чате я использовал два потока:1-читает все сообщения и выводит их на консоль,другой считывает сообщения с консоли и отправляет их.
Примерный код:

```
//читает сообщения и выводит их
private class ReadThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            System.out.println("ReadThread running...");
            while(!stop){
                //reader - BufferedReader,ресурс сообщений
                System.out.println(reader.readLine());

            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("ReadThread closed...");
        }
    }
}

    //читает с консоли и отправляет сообщения
    private class SendThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            String userStr = "";
            while(!userStr.equals("_exit_")){
                userStr = scanner.nextLine();
                writer.println(userStr); //writer - PrintWriter-для отправки сообщений
            }

        }
    }
```